# javascript popup is not loading the html form properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an already existing site and I want to place a popup window that would let a user enter their name and email if they want to be contacted. There's an option to close the popup if you don't desire to be contacted.

It works well on all other places but when I put it on my remote server it conflicts with the page. Below is the code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="target" content="Primary School">
<meta name="Classification" content="Nursery School">
<meta name="Description" content="academy prides itself as home to up to date modern facilities and a concise learning system that has been created to maximise the learning experience for your ward.">
<meta name="Keywords" content="Primary School In, Primary School, Nursery School In , Nursery School In , Primary School In , Nursery School In ">
<title> - Primary School,  Nursery School, Primary School</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- 
To learn more about the conditional comments around the html tags at the top of the file:
paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Do the following if you're using your customized build of modernizr (http://www.modernizr.com/):
* insert the link to your js here
* remove the link below to the html5shiv
* add the "no-js" class to the html tags at the top
* you can also remove the link to respond.min.js if you included the MQ Polyfill in your modernizr build 
-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="verticalscroller.js"></script>
<link href="css/js-image-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/slider_main.css">
<script src="bootstrap/jhoverstatemob.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/facslider.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/searchmarch.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/auto_cycle.js"></script>





<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="flexy-menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$(".flexy-menu").flexymenu({speed: 400,type: "vertical", indicator: true});});</script>
<link href="flexy-menu.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="Bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="modal.css.css" rel="stylesheet">

<form action="sendresults1.php" method="post" id="form_pp" >
  <div id="Modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <div class="modal-header" style="margin-top:120px;">
                <div class="modal-body" > 

                            <div class="form-group">  
                                <input class="form-control"  placeholder= "YOUR FULL NAME" name="name" type="text" autofocus>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">  
                                <input class="form-control"  placeholder= "YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS" name="email" type="Phone number"a>  
                            </div>
                        
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default " style="color:#c13b01" id="btn_send" >SEND</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="color:#c13b01" id="btn_cancel" data-dismiss="modal" >CANCEL</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#Modal').modal('show');
    });
</script>


<script>
var timeout = 500;
var closetimer = 0;
var ddmenuitem = 0;

// open hidden layer
function mopen(id)
{ 
 // cancel close timer
 mcancelclosetime();

 // close old layer
 if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';

 // get new layer and show it
 ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
 ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';

}
// close showed layer
function mclose()
{
 if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

// go close timer
function mclosetime()
{
 closetimer = window.setTimeout(mclose, timeout);
}

// cancel close timer
function mcancelclosetime()
{
 if(closetimer)
 {
  window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
  closetimer = null;
 }
}

// close layer when click-out
document.onclick = mclose; 
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.bxslider.css" type="text/css" />
  
  <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  
  <script src="jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
  <script src="rainbow.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36499930-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

  </script>

</head>
<body style="background-color:#EEE;">
<div id="general_container">
<div id="header">
  
  
        
</div>
<div id="menu2">

<?php include("menu.php") ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  autoControls: true
});
  });
</script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="banner">
           <ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img style="width:100%" src="images/12106739_1690926401119209_2191482622687128165_n.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img style="width:100%" src="images/12088542_1690925387785977_5181459114852166975_n.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img style="width:100%" src="images/12115497_1690998707778645_8753366621948913051_n.jpg" /></li>

</ul>
        
        </div>
       
        <div class="banner_caption"><p>Welcome to <br>SANG BLEU ACADEMY</p></div>
  <div id="text_area">
          
                <div class="text_area_right">
                  <div class="text_area_about">
                          <div class="about_content">
                                <div class="about_content_img"></div>
                                <p style="margin-top:-4px;">
Sang Bleu academy prides itself as home to up to date modern facilities and a concise learning system that has been created to maximise the learning experience for your ward. It will be a privilege to me and my team of dedicated staff to guide your ward in their journey of learning and development.</p>
<a href="about_us.php">Read More</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="about_login">
                                <img src="images/admission.jpg" />
                                 <a href="admission.php" style="text-decoration:none;"><h1 style="font-size:18px; background-color:#FF670F; color:#FFF; font-weight:normal; padding-left:15px;">ADMISSION FORMS</h1></a>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gallery_content">
                          <div class="gallery_content_div">
                                <h1>SCHOOL GATEWAY</h1>
                                <img src="images/line.jpg" style="margin-top:-35px;"/>
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/payment.fw.png" style="margin-top:-15px;"/></a>
                    

                                </div>
                                <div class="gallery_content_div">
                                <h1>HEALTHY & STAYING SAFE</h1>
                    <img src="images/line.jpg" style="margin-top:-35px;"/>
                    <P>Your child's safety and well being are our first priority. </P>
                                </div>
                                <div class="gallery_content_div" style="margin-right:0px;">
                                <h1>POSITIVE CONTRIBUTION</h1>
                    <img src="images/line.jpg" style="margin-top:-35px;"/>
                    <p>We focus on fun and creativity which gets children thinking for themselves.</p>

                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text_area_left">
                  <?php include("login.php") ?>
                </div>
        </div>
        
</div>
</div>
<?php include("footer.php") ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what your issue is? What do you mean it conflicts?

Comment: @matthew-herbst The popup that is supposed to appear once the page loads is aligning to the left behind the menu bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using twice Jquery/Css files in your page, please make sure you are using correct sequence and required js/css.

In your above code your are using extra files please remove

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="Bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And check properly all required js/css.

Comment: thanks. I got it figured out. One of the css was actually doctored by a colleague.